# trocar data-src por src com javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

No site que eu estou fazendo tenho um monte de thumbnail na qual quando clicado vai para outra página onde há vários blocos de código. Cada bloco corresponde a um thumb. O problema é que eu preciso que quando for pra outra página ele não carregue nenhum `<iframe>` exceto o do thumb que eu cliquei. Eu achei um código aqui mesmo no stak em inglês mas não serve exatamente para o propósito e como estou iniciando em back-end recorri a vocês.

### Página inicial

Vamos supor que essa tag de link seja um thumb que ao clicar vai para interna.php

```
<a href="interna.php#thumb1" class="thumb" ></a>
```

### Página interna

Quando estiver na interna o código troca Data-src por src para assim carregar o video em questão

```
<div id="thumb1">
    <iframe width="820" height="420" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eBordIVMoDQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

### Código que estou a usar

Código encontrado no StackOverflow

```
$('.thumb').on("click", "img", function () {
var t = this;
var source = $(t).children("iframe");        
$source.attr({
    src: $t.attr('data-src')

  }).removeAttr('data-src');
}
```

Este é o código resolvido (obs: fiz na mesma página com pop-up):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var iframes = $('iframe');  
        $('.button').click(function() {
            iframes.attr('src', function() {
                var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
                $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
                return src;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: O seu iframe já está usando `src` de iniciou. Não tá errado isto?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim foi só um erro de digitação, mas mesmo assim eu não consigo obter êxito aqui no meu código.

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Não edite a pergunta para adicionar uma resposta, para isto use o botão "Responder", por favor leia o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: A página inicial é uma e a interna.php é outra? O que acontece atualmente?

Answer (score 1):

Neste código que colocaste tem vários problemas:

```
$('.thumb').on("click", "img", function () {
    var t = this;
    var source = $(t).children("iframe");        
    $source.attr({
        src: $t.attr('data-src')
      }).removeAttr('data-src');
}
```

- falta `)` no final depois de `}`
- falta `$` no nome da variável aqui `var source = ...`
- `$t` não existe, nunca foi declarado

Sugestão de código para mudar o `src` da iFrame seria:

```
$('.thumb').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = this.getAttribute("href").split('#');
    var id = src.pop();
    var url = src[0];
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#' + id + ' iframe');
    iframe.src = iframe.dataset.src;
});
```

Por passos:

- evita que o link seja seguido
- extrai o que está no `href` da âncora
- separa em `id` e `url`. (**Nota:** não percebo para que precisas deste `interna.php`?)
- seleciona a `iFrame` usando a `id` que fomos buscar à ancora`
- atribui à iFrame o `src` que está no seu próprio `data-src`

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/y08tn7r0/